# ul li navbar has links showing up as vertical, bullet-point list no matter how I style them?

Tags: css, list, hyperlink, html-lists

I'm using this code to make responsive links (that is, having them highlighted when the viewer is on the page they link to):

http://www.hicksdesign.co.uk/else/cssnav/

This entails coding a simple html navbar with IDs.

However, the navbar I created for some reason has the links structured as a vertical list. Am I missing something obvious, or is this a browser-sider glitch? The code I got from said page had its list horizontal, so I'm having a hard time seeing why it would even format this way. Oddly, the links don't change color when hovered, so I don't think the li a:hover styling is working either.

Here is the page I'm using it on (https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/33061840/site/responsivedesigntest.html), and here is the portion of css styling the links.

```
#navcontainer ul {
    border: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;

}

#navcontainer ul li {
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

#navcontainer ul li a {
    border-right: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 0 10px 0;
    color: #f5d7b4;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    font: normal 10px/18px "Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans Unicode", verdana, lucida, sans-serif;
}

#navcontainer ul li a:hover {
    color: #930;
    background: #f5d7b4;
}
```

Comment: Fixed, but the hover and vertical list issues are still there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your selectors are wrong!

`#navcontainer ul` doesn't exist. Instead you have an id `navlist` on your `ul` element.

**This do the trick:**

Look at how `<b>NAVIGATE:</b>` has been moved from inside the `ul` and look at the CSS changes below.

```
<div class="section group">
    <div class="col span_1_of_2">
                <b>NAVIGATE:</b>
                            <ul id="navlist"> 
                                <li><a href="home.html" id="home"</a>Home</li>
                                <li><a href="zukan.html" id="zukan">Zukan</a></li>
                                <li><a href="Stamps" id="stamps">Stamps</a></li>
                                <li><a href="Photography" id="photography">Photos</a></li>
                            </ul>
            </div>
</div>
```

--

```
#navlist {
    border: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
}

#navlist li {
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 0;
}

#navlist li a {
    border-right: none;
    padding: 0;
    color: #f5d7b4;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    font: normal 10px/18px "Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans Unicode", verdana, lucida, sans-serif;
}

#navlist li a:hover {
    color: #930;
    background: #f5d7b4;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/h2Xg5/1/

Be careful when copying code from tutorials, always double check what you are copying!

Comment: That's really odd... I changed it to navlist but it wasn't working, but when I pasted your code it did. Did you change anything else basides the id? Maybe it's a Kimodo glitch.

Comment: No it's not a glitch, there were problems with your CSS as well. Please look into the details of the changes and compare them to your previous code. I added a `padding` of the value 10px on all sides for the `li` elements.

Comment: Would that alone change it from a vertical to horizontal list? I removed the padding and it's still horizontal.

Comment: No the padding will only separate the elements from each other. You horizontal alignment problem was due to the bad selectors you used. You were using `#navcontainer ul` which doesn't exist, thus your CSS was never applied to your elements and the browser rendered them as a regular un-ordered list.

Comment: I think I understand--but what I'm saying is that I changed the selectors before you posted and nothing changed, but when I c/p'd your code it worked. Must have been a Komodo glitch I guess. Thank you for your help though. While you're still looking at this, is it possible to have "NAVIGATE" on the same line as the links? When I put it outside of <ul id="navlist"> it goes on the line above it.

Comment: I cannot write the code for you, my advice for you is to experiment with CSS `float` property and replacing `<b>NAVIGATION</b>` with `<p><strong>NAVIGATION</strong></p>`.